# PyGTK: copy matplotlib figure to clipboard

Tags: python, gtk, matplotlib, pygtk

I'm working on PyGTK application, that can generate graphs. This achieved by matplotlib. How can I add Copy-To-Clipboard functionality? How to copy figure to clipboard?

Comment: I suppose you want the contents as a plain image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it in Linux (just mouse-click on the image and it is copied to clipboard ready to paste in e.g. GIMP):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import FigureCanvasGTK as FigureCanvas
import gtk
import numpy as np

class W(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        img = np.random.uniform(0,1,(200,200))

        fig = plt.Figure()
        fig.gca().imshow(img)
        self.image_canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        self.image_canvas.connect('button_press_event', self.do_clip)

        self.add(self.image_canvas)
        self.show_all()

    def do_clip(self, widget=None, event=None):

        snap = self.image_canvas.get_snapshot()
        pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_get_from_drawable(None, snap,
            snap.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,
            snap.get_size()[0], snap.get_size()[1])
        clip = gtk.Clipboard()
        clip.set_image(pixbuf)


w=W()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thank you. This code shows me everything what I need. And it also works flawless on windows